# How to efficiently replace partial strings in pandas?

Tags: regex, string, python-3.x, pandas, replace

**Objective:** to reformat the contents of a pandas dataframe based on what has been provided to me.

I have the following dataframe:
[image: Example dataframe]

I am looking to change each column with the following style:

[image]

I am using the following code to produce the style I need, but it is not efficient:

```
lt = []
for i in patterns['Components'][0]:
    for x in i.split('__'):
        lt.append(x)
lt[1].replace('(','').replace(', ',' < '+str(lt[0])+' ≤ ').replace(']','')
```

I have attempted [Pandas Replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) to no avail - it throws no errors and seems to ignore what I am aiming to do.

Comment: Are all the columns of type string? What do you get when you `type(df.Components.iloc[0])`?

Comment: non-null object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Source DF:**

```
In [37]: df
Out[37]:
                           Components                             Outcome
0          (Quantity__(0.0, 16199.0])  (UnitPrice__(-1055.648, 3947.558])
1  (UnitPrice__(-1055.648, 3947.558])          (Quantity__(0.0, 16199.0])
```

**Solution:**

```
In [38]: cols = ['Components','Outcome']
    ...: df[cols] = df[cols].replace(r'\(([^_]*)__\(([^,\s]+),\s*([^\]]+)\]\).*',
    ...:                             r'\2 < \1 <= \3',
    ...:                             regex=True)
```

**Result:**

```
In [39]: df
Out[39]:
                          Components                            Outcome
0          0.0 < Quantity <= 16199.0  -1055.648 < UnitPrice <= 3947.558
1  -1055.648 < UnitPrice <= 3947.558          0.0 < Quantity <= 16199.0
```

**UPDATE:**

```
In [113]: df
Out[113]:
                                Components                               Outcome
0             (Quantity__(0.0, 16199.0])     (UnitPrice__(-1055.648, 3947.558])
1    (UnitPrice__(-1055.648, 3947.558])             (Quantity__(0.0, 16199.0])

In [114]: cols = ['Components','Outcome']

In [115]: pat = r'\s*\(([^_]*)__\(([^,\s]+),\s*([^\]]+)\]\)\s*'

In [116]: df[cols] = df[cols].replace(pat, r'\2 < \1 <= \3', regex=True)

In [117]: df
Out[117]:
                          Components                            Outcome
0          0.0 < Quantity <= 16199.0  -1055.648 < UnitPrice <= 3947.558
1  -1055.648 < UnitPrice <= 3947.558          0.0 < Quantity <= 16199.0
```

or witout parentheses:

```
In [119]: df
Out[119]:
                         Components                           Outcome
0         Quantity__(0.0, 16199.0])  UnitPrice__(-1055.648, 3947.558]
1  UnitPrice__(-1055.648, 3947.558]          Quantity__(0.0, 16199.0]

In [120]: pat = r'([^_]*)__\(([^,\s]+),\s*([^\]]+)\]'

In [121]: df[cols] = df[cols].replace(pat, r'\2 < \1 <= \3', regex=True)

In [122]: df
Out[122]:
                          Components                            Outcome
0         0.0 < Quantity <= 16199.0)  -1055.648 < UnitPrice <= 3947.558
1  -1055.648 < UnitPrice <= 3947.558          0.0 < Quantity <= 16199.0
```

Comment: your solution looks wonderful, but I only get back the original results of the dataframe (nothing new). In case it matters, the original results in the Pandas dataframe (['Components','Outcome']) are both non-null objects.

Comment: @Student, that means that your real data (strings) are slightly different and your sample data set is not reproducible - because of that the RegEx is working for your sample DF and isn't working on your real data.... Can you provide a __reproducible__ sample data set (__in text__ format, so we could copy and paste it)?

Comment: I ran the following: 
patterns['Components'][0],df['Components'][0] 

which produced the following: 
(frozenset({'Quantity__(0.0, 16199.0]'}), '(Quantity__(0.0, 16199.0])'). I am not sure if this is helpful, but all I have is the output from the original dataframe (patterns).

Since you theorized that the two dataframe's may not be the same (and they are not based on patterns=df=False), I have tried to cleanup stuff with patterns.replace('(^\s+|\s+$)', '', regex=True, inplace=True). At present, this has made no difference in the output.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import re
data=pd.DataFrame({'components':
['(quantity__(0.0,16199.0])','(unitprice__(-1055.648,8494.557])'],'outcome':
['(unitprice__(-1055.648,8494.557])','quantity__(0.0,16199.0])']})


def func(x):
    x=str(x)
    x=x.split('__')
    dx=x[0].replace("(",'')
    mt=re.findall('\d*\.\d*',x[1])
    return('{}<{}<={}'.format(dx,mt[0],mt[1]))


df=data.applymap(func)
print(df)
```